# Best way for using Java Application to connect and retrieve data from Application Server

Tags: java, jboss, fetch, application-server

Assume that I have an application server JBoss which hold inside some data, and I want to write a small Java application to retrieve these data. Is my solution below a good one to solve this problem?

1. In order that the Application Server can have some data, I will create a Java Web Application with some mock data inside and then I will deploy this application to the JBoss application server. When the application is deployed, it will have an URL to access (I think so).
2. Create a normal Java Application to retrieve this data by connecting to the URL of the Web Application above. But my question here raising up that how to connect my Java Application to this Web Application, more generally I mean how to fetch data from an Application Server to my Java Application? Sorry that my question might seem amateur but hope to receive ideas from you ;)

Comment: I am not clear. Is your server a REST server with endpoints?
Or are you mocking a server?

Comment: Hi Shenal, I would say it's just a mock server running localhost on my machine

Answer (score 1):

A simple standalone java class can be used to get data from web application through http protocol  using http client provided by Apache.You required below jars
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-httpclient-3.0
commons-logging-1.0.3

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("URL");
HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
post.setRequestEntity(new InputStreamRequestEntity(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes()), s.length()));
try 
{
     int result = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
     System.out.println("Response status code: " + result);
     System.out.println("Response body: ");
     System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
 } 
 finally
 {
     post.releaseConnection();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can choose between a Restful or Soap application, Remote method invocation, (RMI), or old school socket listener, the last is the easiest option for a small scale software in terms of learning curve.

If you want a browser application you need to use the http based methods which are REST or SOAP.

Comment: Thank you Yan, I will have a look on these methods!

Comment: " it will always connect to the application server and retrieve data continuously every time the data in the application server are updated" - Implementation is up to you, you can rise a flag on data update from server, and initiate client call to server every X time period to check that flag, you can't initiate a server call to client unless it is also a server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RESTful services. Below is the sample code to call from a java application to a RESTful service deployed on a server. ***com.sun.jersey*** has simple libraries to achieve your goal.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;


    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource resource = client.resource("www.example.com/api");
    ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
    String json=response.getEntity(String.class);
```

You can refer to below link for more information:

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

Answer (score 0):

Personally in this situation i will use EJB from client and Server.

This able you to use datasource like normal class.
For example:

```
ejb.addUser(user)
```

So this is very comfortable.

And on EJB you can create REST app whenever you want

Comment: Hi Razikus, I am not very familiar with EJB, do you have any more details example or tutorial on this. Thank you in advanced !

Comment: So i don't have good tutorials for this. All of it are bad or old or doesn't meet my requirements, but when i arrive home i will edit this answer and add here what i personally know about, and process from null to configure persistence with EJB with WildFly10

Comment: thanks Razikus, hope to receive answer soon from you :)

Comment: Sorry, that i dont answer you yesterday
Try to read this source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fwrpnenqpj4xj1/KEY.zip?dl=0